# Need to add a node at a specific position in XML in QTP

Tags: xml, tags, qtp

I need to add a node at a specific position. please check the example below.

```
<root>
<ASNHeader>
<ASNStart>text</ASNStart>
<ASNprop>text_prop</ASNprop>
<ASNDetail>
<ASNAprvr>Mr.X</ASNAprvr>
<ASNAprvrDt>20Mar</ASNAprvrDT>
<ASNAprvrSub>XXX</ASNAprvrsUB>
</ASNDetail>
<ASNSHIP>XYZ</ASNSHIP>
<ASNSRDC>XYZ123</ASNSRDC>
</ASNHeader>
</root>
```

Here i have to copy "ASNDetail" tag and paste it after existing "ASNDetail" and before "ASNSHIP" tag. I need to copy paste this based on the number of times user specifies.
Note: I have to do this in QTP and i'm using MSXML2.DomDocument as xml parser. can anyone suggest a way. AppendChild copies it after "ASNSRDC" tag but i don't want in this way.
Here "ASNHeader" is child of "root". ASNDetail is child of "root\ASNHeader". I am not format the code properly in this post. kindly adjust.

Comment: I have got the solution through insertBefore command(thought it would work only for Jscript,C#)..but its working for QTP too..would post the code tomorrow morning..

Comment: Solution:

Set xmldom = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
xmldom.Load("C:\Sample\test.xml")

'Code to cpoy the tag
Set ndClnDtl = xmldom.selectSingleNode("/root/ASNHeader/ASNDetail").cloneNode(true)

'Location at which you need to cop the xml tags
Set specNode = xmldom.selectSingleNode("/root/ASNHeader/ASNSHIP")

'Rtnode is parent to the location mentioned
Set Rtnode = xmldom.selectSingleNode("/root/ASNHeader")
Rtnode.insertBefore ndClnDtl,specNode
xmldom.Save("C:\Sample\test.xml")

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
Set xmldom = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
xmldom.Load(C:\Sample\test.xml")

'Code to cpoy the tag
Set ndClnDtl = xmldom.selectSingleNode("/root/ASNHeader/ASNDetail").cloneNode(true)

'Location at which you need to cop the xml tags
Set specNode = xmldom.selectSingleNode("/root/ASNHeader/ASNSHIP")

'Rtnode is parent to the location mentioned
Set Rtnode = xmldom.selectSingleNode("/root/ASNHeader")
Rtnode.insertBefore ndClnDtl,specNode

xmldom.Save("C:\Sample\test.xml")
```